# How to reduce array's numeric values, skipping strings

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, reduce

Using Google Sheets' Script Editor, I need to calculate the **average of each column** of a table such as this one:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |  User 1 |  User 2 |  User 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         | 20/1/17 | 21/1/17 | 22/1/17 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Movie 1 |    6    |    2    |    0    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| Movie 2 |    2    |    1    |    5    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Movie 3 |    3    |    1    |    2    | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want the result to be:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|  User 1 |  User 2 |  User 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+   
|   3.6   |   1.3   |   2.3   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have this code, which works if I use it on a table composed by numbers only. The problem is my table has strings in it, so the .reduce returns a #NUM! error (Result was not a number).

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  e.forEach(function(a, j) {
    r[j] = (r[j] || 0) + a
  })
  if (i == array.length - 1) r = r.map(function(el) {
    return el / array.length
  });
  return r;
}, []);

return sum;
```

**How can I perform the average with the numeric values only?** I tried using .filter, but it didn't seem to work on Google Apps Script Editor, or maybe I was just using it wrong (very likely).

This is the condition I was using to filter:

```
(typeof el !== 'number')
```

Comment: Is you r data such that you can remove the first two items from array or skip over them in the foreach without testing?  Basically start at the row which should be the first, `if (r < 2) return;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following sample? You can use this on Google Apps Script.

```
var array = [
            [,, 'User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'],
            ['Movie 1', '20/1/17', 6.0, 2.0, 5.0],
            ['Movie 2', '21/1/17', 2.0, 0.0, 2.0],
            ['Movie 3', '22/1/17', 3.0, 1.0, 3.0]
            ];

var sum = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  e.forEach(function(a, j) {
      r[j] = (parseInt(r[j]) || 0) + a;
  })
  if (i == array.length - 1) r = r.map(function(el) {
    return isFinite(el) ? el : "";
  });
  return r;
}, []);
return [array[0].splice(2, 3), [x for each (x in sum)].splice(2, 3)];

>>> [[User 1, User 2, User 3], [11.0, 3.0, 10.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike. This is pretty much what I need, except I wrote the table wrong (sorry), and the dates are actually on the same columns as the users (it's fixed now), so they are being added on the sum (I guess it's because of that parseInt, but I can't manage to make it work without it).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not found the logic to be obtained the result of [3.6, 1.3, 2.3] from the table you modified. So I cannot update my sample script. Can I ask you about the logic?

Comment: It's the average of each column. So the first column [6, 2, 3] is (6+2+3)/3 = 3.5. So first I need to sum them (as you did in your script) and then divide them by the amount of rows.

Comment: Well, nevermind. I just dropped the row with the dates and now your solution works :) Thank you!